# IPv6 and OpenVPN

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, openvpn, ipv6

I have a question about a 'theoretical' configuration, I wanted to see if it is achievable and further if it is common practice

I am not new to Ubuntu but I am no pro, I am using Ubuntu server 20.04

context:
It is a cloud server that has a singular external IPv4 address and its own external IPv6 subnet. It is configured with NetPlan (if that is relevant)

I will work out on making OpenVPN IPv6 only so lets forget about IPv4

My question

Is there a way I can assign a pool of external IPv6 addresses either to the server/openVPN so that client connections just pick an external IP at random? (external being the important part). It does not matter if OpenVPN does this or the OS, if it works it works. Really couldn't care if I have to setup some other application either, a solution is a solution and I am not fussy

Thank you in advanced for any help, appreciate it

UPDATE:

Just noticed I can edit, I have managed to add a ton of IPv6 addresses in via NetPlan now and they are working however in an ideal world I would like to define which one of those is used by the OS as I would not want the OS to be using the same address as a VPN client